# PHP: difference between returning 1,-1 and 0?

Tags: php

What is the difference between returning 1,-1 and 0 in PHP? What do they signify? What I want to know is that, is 'return 1' referring to true or false? And similarly about 'return -1' and 'return 0'.

Comment: They don't signify anything, they're just numbers. Is there a particular context you're referring to?

Comment: Well, they are three different integer values.

Comment: This completely depends on where you are seeing this and what the return value is being used for...

Comment: What type of returns are you referring to?

Comment: In the context of a user sort callback, they signify less than, equal or greater than comparison results; but you haven't given any context for your question

Comment: What I want to know is that, is 'return 1' referring to true or false? And similarly about 'return -1' and 'return 0'.

Comment: 1 is true 0 stands for false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you're asking about comparison functions use with `usort()`, as that's the only place where it's typical to return 1, -1, or 0.

In this case, `1` means that the first value is greater than the second, `-1` means the first value is less than the second, and `0` means the values are equal. Although `usort()` doesn't actually require you to return these specific values -- all it cares about is whether the value is positive, negative, or zero. This allows you to write a comparison function like:

```
function compare_f($a, $b) {
    return f($a) - f($b);
}
```

If you're asking about `true`/`false` contexts, see http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php. It says:

> When converting to boolean, the following values are considered FALSE:
>
> - the boolean FALSE itself
> - the integer 0 (zero)
> - the float 0.0 (zero)
> - the empty string, and the string "0"
> - an array with zero elements
> - an object with zero member variables (PHP 4 only)
> - the special type NULL (including unset variables)
> - SimpleXML objects created from empty tags
>
> Every other value is considered TRUE (including any resource).

Answer (score 0):

It's not about PHP. It is about shell-conventions. `0` is a convention for "everything is fine" other numbers mean that something is wrong, but exact meaning is application-specific

So, if your script returns to shell with `exit(0);` the caller knows that it was successful, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that the answer you are looking for is that these values are "Truthy" and "Falsey" values.

They are not booleans as `true` and `false` are. However, evaluating them will equate to either true or false values for the purposes of `if()` or `while()` statements.

Here is some more reading on true, false, truthy, and falsey:

http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php

Answer (score 0):

PHP will evaluate `0` as `false` and `1` as `true` - Meaning it behaves like a Boolean.

```
if (1) echo 'true';
if (0) echo 'false';
// result: true
```

With that said, `if(-1)` will also return true as would `if(1000)` so as it has already been stated it really does depend on context.